# Using two different regression models on one dataset to predict a single label

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression, sklearn-pandas

I wanted to use KNN on features which were textmined while using another type of regression for the rest of my features. Is it possible to somehow combine both regression models to predict a single label? Should I split my datasets into two different ones?

I am currently using pandas and sklearn.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do that using Ensemble models.

Ensemble models combine decisions from various models in order to improve the overall performance. For regression problems I would suggest the following ensemble models/techniques:

**Averaging**

Is a fairly simple ensemble technique where you need to take the average of the predictions from all of your models and use it to make the final prediction.

**Weighted Averaging**

This is similar to simple averaging, but all of the models are now assgined different weights, defining the importance/contribution of each of the models in the final prediction.

**Bagging meta-estimator**

Is an ensembling technique that can be used in both classification ([`BaggingClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html)) and regression ([`BaggingRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingRegressor.html)). Bagging meta-estimator undertakes the following steps in order to reach to the final prediction:

1. Randomly create subsets out of the original dataset
2. A base estimator is fitted on each of the subsets created in step 1.
3. Predictions are combined to get the final predicted label

Below is a very simple example that makes use of `BaggingRegressor` of `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor

ensemble_model = BaggingRegressor(tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1))
ensemble_model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
ensemble_model.score(X_test,Y_test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have a question regarding the Baggomg meta-estimator, is it possible to manually select the otherwise randomly created subsets?